# Deploy Chrome extension settings update?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I work in a corporate environment and we are trying to deploy settings for a Chrome extension to minimize user required steps. I've learned that these settings are stored in a leveldb located at %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb

I'm having trouble finding an existing solution for this. I am personally limited to powershell or vbscript and I'm comfortable with working with binary data. I would like to know if there is some API I can use to edit these settings of if I'm going to have to ensure that Chrome is closed and modify the db directly? If I can modify the db from powershell or vbscript then that would be ideal. If this requires a compiled app then I'll start going down that path

It looks like if we deploy the log file from the local extension settings folder that the settings seem to apply but this to me seems like a glitch/hack and not something we should rely on. Any ideas? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer you a solution that you may not like.
Editing \ replacing the .ldb files may invalidate the extension. Have you already done a test replacing this file(s) to see if it works?

If you have developed the extension (or if you have some relationship with the developer) you could ask users to inspect the extension options page (or background script) and paste a script into the devtoolos console.

Normally the extension parameters are stored in the localStorage or in the chrome.storage object but they could also be in an indexexDB.
So it shouldn't be too difficult to create that script and explain the steps to users.
Maybe you can even make a short explanatory video.

Comment: We are able to provide short documentation to end users and it really isn't that difficult, at least not for me. I'm at Tier 3 trying to provide something to admins who could hopefully deploy this to hundreds of thousands of users. Some users user shared workstations and so they may log into 50 different computers.

Comment: As for the extension, it's the Microsoft S/MIME so working with them to modify the extension is likely not an option. I'm able to look at the js for the extension and I've considered modifying that but it is copyrighted so I don't think can be done legally

Comment: The code may be minified\obfuscated but nobody can forbid you from opening the console and play with some API.
Try first to understand where these settings are stored.
I don't mean physically, but through the tools of the developers tool (devtools console).
Usually the settings are stored in localStorage section (easy to verify) or in the chrome.storage object
(which you can inspect running chrome.storage.local.get(null, console.log) in console).
If you want to try the replacement of the leveldb file you should make a small package (i.e bat file) and teach you users how to use it\run it.

Comment: Well, for end user interaction, I already have some easy to follow documentation including pictures that a 5yo could follow. It's as simple as opening the settings and adding a few URLs. What I'm hoping to provide is a way for admins to deploy the settings with no user interaction to minimize user error.

Comment: We have tested replacing the .log files in the local extension settings folder which seems to work but I don't consider this reliable due to what I read about leveldb. Those log files are treated as virtual memory. I have NOT verified whether manual changes to the log file are replicated to the actual database (.ldb). Another idea I had on this is to develop a custom extension to modify the settings of the S/MIME extension. I haven't looked yet to see if this is even possible. I would much prefer to have a script or app do this externally

Comment: you can ask for some hint at
  
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions